# Removal of Parallel Ghost Points in .vtu Files with vtkGhostType

Tags: vtk, paraview

I am trying to write and visualise an unstructured mesh (`.pvtu`/`.vtu`) and I can't seem to get the point and cell `vtkGhostType` worked out to obtain the result I want.

From our code, we use a 1 cell/element overlap. Thus multiple domains contain the same cells, but critically no domain is the 'master' of these shared cells. Further, we solve for data at vertices, which means that we also have duplicate nodes. However, here there is a 'slave-master' relationship with one 'master' and potentially multiple 'slaves'. What I would like is to remove the duplicate(slaves) nodes, but retain at least 1 of the duplicate cells.

My .pvtu file contains the following:

```xml
<VTKFile type="PUnstructuredGrid" version="1.0" byte_order="LittleEndian">
<PUnstructuredGrid>
<PPointData>
    <PDataArray NumberOfComponents="1" type="Float64" Name="Volume" format="ascii">
    </PDataArray>
    <PDataArray type="UInt8" Name="vtkGhostType" format="ascii">
    </PDataArray>
</PPointData>
<PCellData>
    <PDataArray type="UInt8" Name="vtkGhostType" format="ascii">
  </PDataArray> 
</PCellData>
<PPoints>
    <PDataArray NumberOfComponents="3" type="Float64" Name="Points" format="ascii">
    </PDataArray>
</PPoints>
<PCells>
    <PDataArray type="Int32" Name="connectivity" format="ascii">
    </PDataArray>
    <PDataArray type="Int32" Name="offsets" format="ascii">
    </PDataArray>
    <PDataArray type="Int32" Name="types" format="ascii">
    </PDataArray>
</PCells>
<Piece Source="paraview_1_domain_0.vtu"/>
<Piece Source="paraview_1_domain_1.vtu"/>
</PUnstructuredGrid>
</VTKFile>
```

and the two .vtu files, `paraview_1_domain_0.vtu` (Note The slave node `Volume` value of `5` is incorrect and should not be rendered)

```xml
<VTKFile type="UnstructuredGrid" version="1.0" byte_order="LittleEndian">
    <UnstructuredGrid>
        <Piece NumberOfPoints="6" NumberOfCells="2">
            <PointData>
                <DataArray type="Float64" NumberOfComponents="1" Name="Volume" format="ascii">
                    1.0000000000000000E-00
                    1.0000000000000000E-00
                    2.0000000000000000E-00
                    2.0000000000000000E-00
                    5.0000000000000000E-00
                    3.0000000000000000E-00
                </DataArray> 
                <DataArray type="UInt8" Name="vtkGhostType" format="ascii">
                0
                0
                0
                0
                3
                3
        </DataArray> 
            </PointData>
            <CellData>
                <DataArray type="UInt8" Name="vtkGhostType" format="ascii">
                0
                0
        </DataArray> 
            </CellData>
            <Points>
                <DataArray type="Float64" NumberOfComponents="3" Name="Points" format="ascii">
                    0.0000000000000000E-00  0.0000000000000000E-00  0.0000000000000000E+00
                    0.0000000000000000E-00  1.0000000000000000E-00  0.0000000000000000E+00
                    1.0000000000000000E-00  0.0000000000000000E-00  0.0000000000000000E+00
                    1.0000000000000000E-00  1.0000000000000000E-00  0.0000000000000000E+00
                    2.0000000000000000E-00  0.0000000000000000E-00  0.0000000000000000E+00
                    2.0000000000000000E-00  1.0000000000000000E-00  0.0000000000000000E+00
                </DataArray>
            </Points>
            <Cells>
                <DataArray type="Int32" Name="connectivity" format="ascii">
                    0 2 3 1 3 5 4 2 
                </DataArray>
                <DataArray type="Int32" Name="offsets" format="ascii">
4 8  
                </DataArray>
                <DataArray type="Int32" Name="types" format="ascii">
9 9 
                </DataArray>
            </Cells>
        </Piece>
    </UnstructuredGrid>
</VTKFile>
```

and `paraview_1_domain_1.vtu`

```xml
<VTKFile type="UnstructuredGrid" version="1.0" byte_order="LittleEndian">
    <UnstructuredGrid>
        <Piece NumberOfPoints="6" NumberOfCells="2">
            <PointData>
                <DataArray type="Float64" NumberOfComponents="1" Name="Volume" format="ascii">
                    2.0000000000000000E-00
                    2.0000000000000000E-00
                    3.0000000000000000E-00
                    3.0000000000000000E-00
                    4.0000000000000000E-00
                    4.0000000000000000E-00
                </DataArray> 
                <DataArray type="UInt8" Name="vtkGhostType" format="ascii">
                3
                3
                0
                0
                0
                0
        </DataArray> 
            </PointData>
            <CellData>
                <DataArray type="UInt8" Name="vtkGhostType" format="ascii">
                1
                0
        </DataArray> 
            </CellData>
            <Points>
                <DataArray type="Float64" NumberOfComponents="3" Name="Points" format="ascii">
                    1.0000000000000000E-00  0.0000000000000000E-00  0.0000000000000000E+00
                    1.0000000000000000E-00  1.0000000000000000E-00  0.0000000000000000E+00
                    2.0000000000000000E-00  0.0000000000000000E-00  0.0000000000000000E+00
                    2.0000000000000000E-00  1.0000000000000000E-00  0.0000000000000000E+00
                    3.0000000000000000E-00  0.0000000000000000E-00  0.0000000000000000E+00
                    3.0000000000000000E-00  1.0000000000000000E-00  0.0000000000000000E+00
                </DataArray>
            </Points>
            <Cells>
                <DataArray type="Int32" Name="connectivity" format="ascii">
                    0 2 3 1 3 5 4 2 
                </DataArray>
                <DataArray type="Int32" Name="offsets" format="ascii">
4 8  
                </DataArray>
                <DataArray type="Int32" Name="types" format="ascii">
9 9 
                </DataArray>
            </Cells>
        </Piece>
    </UnstructuredGrid>
</VTKFile>
```

With reference to https://blog.kitware.com/ghost-and-blanking-visibility-changes/ and http://www.visitusers.org/index.php?title=Representing_ghost_data

I set the `vtkGhostType` for the slave nodes to `3` since I do not want them to be used in interpolation. With the above files I can obtain two solutions, neither of which is optimal:

1. Mark all shared cells `CellData:vtkGhostType` with `0` except in one `.vtu` and set to `0`. This give me the following result:

[image]

The two slave vertices from `domain 1` are removed when the `RemoveGhostInfomration` filter is applied. However, as you will notice the volume at one of the slave nodes is set to `5` where it should be `3`. I.e. the slaves from `domain 0` still remain.

2. Mark all shared cells `CellData:vtkGhostType` with `1` This give me the following result:

[image]

Applying the same filter, the correct vertex data is obtained, and all slaves are deleted. However now all cells are removed. Which from a visualisation point of view is undesireable.

The correct results should be 8 nodes (no slaves), 3 cells (no duplicates), and a volume scalar field which varing linearly from 1 to 4 from left to right as shown in the below figure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand the problem. Please correct me if I have something wrong.

The cell in the middle has 2 versions: one per unstructured grid, and each version of this cell has partially the good point values. What you want is to display the correct point values by cherry-picking from the 2 cells.

When rendering, you cannot mix and match points between cells. What you need to do is find a way to migrate all the correct point values to one unstructured grid, and ghost the rest. You can do that with MPI.

I should add that blanking for unstructured grid is not implemented in VTK. Blanking only works for structured grid types (vtkImageData, vtkUniformGrid, vtkRectilinearGrid and vtkStructuredGrid). So vtkDataSetAttributes::HIDDENCELL does nothing for unstructured grids. Only vtkDataSetAttributes::DUPLICATECELL has effects when rendering. A duplicate cell assumes that the data mapped to the cell / point is valid and can be used by filters.